# ( Html2Canvas & jsPDF ) why image cut in chrome ?? (It is not cut off in safari.)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, out-of-memory, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to convert dozens of A4 size pages in react.js

I use html2canvas & jsPDF & sunEditor

In Chrome it is cropped to about 15 pages based on Scale 1. (Scale 2: 8page)

(*I think it is a memory overflow issue.*)

However, it is output normally in Safari.

I will attach the code and image at the bottom.

Any kind advice would be appreciated.

```
const targetDom = this.contentRef.current; 
// var copyDom = targetDom.cloneNode(true);
// document.body.appendChild(copyDom);
 

let option = { 
    scale : 1,
    allowTaint: true,
    backgroundColor:null,
    useCORS: true,   
    logging : true,  
};
let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4')
let canvas = pdf.canvas; 
canvas.width = a4Width; 
await html2canvas(targetDom, option).then ( function (canvas) { 
    
let imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 2.0);
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');    
    
        let width = 0
        for(j = 0; j < len ; j++) { 
            pdf.setPage(j+1);
            console.log('JPEG', width, -1 *(a4Height + margin)* j,width + a4Width, (a4Height + margin)*len - margin) 
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'png', width, -1 *(a4Height + margin)* j, width + a4Width, (a4Height + margin)*len - margin,  undefined, 'slow' );
            if(j < len-1)pdf.addPage(); 
        }  
        pdf.save(`${title}.pdf` );
        // copyDom.remove();
        let link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = 'browser.png';
        link.href = imgData;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        link.remove(); 
    } 
)
```

**under chrome image**

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

**under safari image**

[image: screenshot 3]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue all of the sudden, the issue seems to be due to grammarly chrome extension (maybe recent update).

Here's the Github issue link,

https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/2804

Hopefully this would be helpful.